# hide XML element from appearing in browser

Tags: xml, flash

I have a website which I am setting up. However, I want the first page (Home) not to have any sub menu. When I change the value of true to false all the other pages where I want the drop down to appear also disappear.

I want other pages to have sub menu but not the home page. I have tried to change the xml path etc, but nothing seems to work.

Can somebody please advise on this. I am new to xml and finding this very challenging.

I have uploaded the config.xml and the layout xml's. I have also placed the index.htm and js script there.

http://www.mediafire.com/?sharekey=043102ffea137c3c67cd7f7bd65f7eef3662a86c6a842d54ea4ac78345cbe4ce

Also could someone please help me understand from where it is reading the config.xml.

**UPDATE:**

I checked the SWF and yes the it is pointing to the config file. What I still dont understand is that how can i remove the sub-menu from home while keeping it for other pages.

I have uploaded the entire content of the website at :

http://www.mediafire.com/file/zqqal0kywmf/FD_Unlimited.rar

Thanks for all your help.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

From the swf file you didn't provide.